# переадресация RedirectMatch исключить параметр

Tags: php, .htaccess

На сервере в фоновом режиме происходит ресайзинг изображений, поэтому для контроля кэша сделан след. костыль из переадресаций:
.htaccess

```
RedirectMatch "^/images/uploaded/([0-9]+)/([^\.]+)\.(png|jpg|gif)$" /image_view.php?user_id=$1\&file=$2.$3
```

---

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['file']) && isset($_GET['user_id'])) {
    $path_to_image = 'images/uploaded/' . intval($_GET['user_id']) . '/' . $_GET['file'];
    $modified = filemtime($path_to_image);

    header('Location:' . $path_to_image . '?' . $modified, true, 303);
}
```

Как не сложно догадаться, тут происходит зацикливание, т.к. php генерирует переадресацию по тому же пути, с добавлением параметра $modified , как исключить из htaccess эту переадресацию и учитывать обращения к (png|jpg|gif) без символа "?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть стоит заменить `RedirectMatch` на `RewriteCond` и `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/images\/uploaded\/(\d+)/([^\.]+)\.(png|jpg|gif)$
RewriteRule .* http://your.site/image_view.php?user_id=%1&file=%2.%3 [L]
```

Comment: странно, не сработал редикт

Comment: @aliokero, проверял на localhost c Apache/2.4.10 (Win32). Переадресация работает дописывая timestamp в параметры, зацикливания нет.

Comment: проверил на localhost и продакшене, все равно редирект не происходит( в чем может быть причина?

Comment: @aliokero, `mod_rewrite` у вас включен?

Comment: если директория на сервере существует images , то не происходит переадресации, если изменить на RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/images3\/uploaded\/(\d+)/([^\.]+)\.(png|jpg|gif)$ - images3, то происходит переадресация, флагов не хватает?

Comment: @aliokero, данный вариант должен работать и при существовании файла к которому идет обращение и если его фактически не существует. Правда во втором случае в php скрипте в строке `$modified = filemtime($path_to_image);` вернет false и в параметрах переадресации будет пусто <- тут возможно зацикливание тогда.